# Java: How to split a string while ignoring other parts

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a hyphen separated list of string keys like this:

```
String s = "key-keyone-keytwo";
```

When I use `s.split("-")`, I get an array as `[key, keyone, keytwo]` just as one would expect. Where my problem arises is when I have a key which contains a dash.  I decided I would escape the hyphenated key such that:

```
String s1 = "key-key'-'one-keytwo";
```

When I split String s1 with a hyphen, my result should be `[key, key-one, keytwo]`.

What would I put as a regex for the split so that it would meet the above criteria. I'm not too familiar with regex patterns so an explanation would be awesome too.

**Update**: The word "key" wont be hardcoded. It could be any string. Ideally, I would want something like this `"someString->anotherString->another"` Where I would be able to split the arrow `->` similar to a java lambda. **And if for whatever reason a key string contained an arrow**, it could be escaped like: `"some'->'string->anotherString->another"` and would turn into: `[some->string, anotherString, another]` I know its a bit complicated but any suggestions would help!

Comment: If you can change the key to escape the hyphen, you can change it to add any other character as wel right and then use - to separate as before?

Comment: You are correct, however, doing what you are recommending wouldn't be ideal for the scenario i'm working with

Comment: @Emma Holy cow! This website is awesome. Thank you for sharing! One thing to note is that it won't always be the word "key". It could be any string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to split on `-`, but not on `'-'`, but at the same time you want to replace `'-'` with `-`. You cannot do that with just a `split()` call, since it doesn't do replacement.

You can do the splitting part by splitting on a `-` that isn't preceded *or* followed by a `'`:

```
s.split("(?<!')-|-(?!')")
```

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("key-keyone-keytwo");
    test("key-key-'one-keytwo");
    test("key-key'-one-keytwo");
    test("key-key'-'one-keytwo");
}
private static void test(String str) {
    String[] split = str.split("(?<!')-|-(?!')");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
}
```

*Output*

```
[key, keyone, keytwo]
[key, key, 'one, keytwo]
[key, key', one, keytwo]
[key, key'-'one, keytwo]
```

As you can see, it didn't split on `'-'`, but the result still has that "escape", so you need a followup to fix that:

```
String[] split = str.split("(?<!')-|-(?!')");
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    split[i] = split[i].replaceAll("'-'", "-");
```

*Output*

```
[key, keyone, keytwo]
[key, key, 'one, keytwo]
[key, key', one, keytwo]
[key, key-one, keytwo]
```

You can do that in a single statement using Streams:

```
String[] split = Pattern.compile("(?<!')-|-(?!')")
        .splitAsStream(str)
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll("'-'", "-"))
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Which of course can be written in a single line too:

```
String[] split = Pattern.compile("(?<!')-|-(?!')").splitAsStream(str).map(s -> s.replaceAll("'-'", "-")).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Thanks again for the response and the explanation. Came back to this to the answer to tell you that it helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to answers related for python, Java should have similar capabilities - [Python split string without splitting escaped character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092354/python-split-string-without-splitting-escaped-character)

```
>>> re.split(r'(?<!\')-', "key-key'-'one-keytwo")
  ['key', "key'-'one", 'keytwo']
```

But '-' is not the ideal way to escape the seperators, you can use backslash