# Do not escape string in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, escaping

I fetch some data from file, but after some processing, Python escape backslashes which is not desirable behavior.

Python 3 on Windows 10

```py
line = "URL     ABC     \/A\/B\/C\/D" #line of fetched file
tokens = line.split('\t') # tokens = ['URL', 'ABC', '\\/A\\/B\\/C\\/D']
```

Problem is not the representation of strings in Python. Problem is that I need write the output to the file, so when I try to write `tokens[2]` in to the file, it is wrote `\\/A\\/B\\/C\\/D` instead of `\/A\/B\/C\/D`. Which is wrong output.

Comment: How are you writing it to a file? Can you post a [mre]?

Comment: Maybe this will answer your question: [splitting string without escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092354/python-split-string-without-splitting-escaped-character)

Comment: Python only shows the double backslashes when you're printing the representation of the string, they're not in the string itself and shouldn't be written to the file. You need to show how you're writing to the file and why you think the double backslashes are there.

Comment: Actually, I have a dict, where I save tokens, like this: `pdict[tokens[1]] = tokens[2]`, then I make a json `outJson = json.dumps(pdict, indent=4)` and then write into file: `outfile.write(outJson)`

Comment: Backslashes are always escaped in json files. It's part of the json specification.

Comment: Json is a microdatabase for regular expressions. So ok, so lets keep strings escaped. How can I unescape them for use them as regular expression? Like: `re.compile(tokens[2])`? It doesn't work with escaping.

Comment: Ok, I was confused about `match` and `search`. Everything works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

try to unescape your string with : 
add this after your split

`line = "URL     ABC     \/A\/B\/C\/D" #line of fetched file
tokens = line.split('\t') # tokens = ['URL', 'ABC', '\\/A\\/B\\/C\\/D']
tokens[2]=tokens[2].decode('string_escape') ;`

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Answer (score -1):

You need to grab it as a raw string so instead of

```
line = "URL     ABC     \/A\/B\/C\/D" #line of fetched file
tokens = line.split('\t') # tokens = ['URL', 'ABC', '\\/A\\/B\\/C\\/D']
```

you need to add an `r` before the string, that way nothing can escape.

```
line = r"URL     ABC     \/A\/B\/C\/D" #line of fetched file
tokens = line.split('\t') # tokens = ['URL', 'ABC', '\\/A\\/B\\/C\\/D']
```

Comment: That gives exactly the same result, because `'\/'` is not a valid escape character so is interpreted the same as `'\\/'` or `r'\/'`.